# Return only those rows with a date on or before today using Query and Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

In Google Sheets I have a QUERY where I want to import only those rows where the dates in `Col23` are on or before today's date.

This is my current formula:

```
=QUERY(
   IMPORTRANGE(
     "1PfXYlqZ6UBbhemljYDMKUJvQJlRY6aTTVz825yHPrPk","Jan!A1:W"),
   "SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col22,Col23 where Col16
    contains 'Sent' and Col23 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rows where a date is less than or equal to today in a `query()`, use the *less than or equal to* operator `<=`:

```
where Col16 contains 'Sent' and Col23 <= date " & text(today(), "'yyyy-MM-dd'")
```

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)